# The python <- operator: what does it mean?

Tags: python, operators

I am going through a Python/Pygame tutorial.  I came across this `<-` operator.  What does it mean?

Here's the line of code:

```
if bullet[1]<-64 or bullet[1]>640 or bullet[2]<-64 or bullet[2]>480:
    arrows.pop(index)
```

Comment: This would be considered poorly formatted code, and if this is in a tutorial you need to make sure you don't pick up their formatting style.

Comment: With the code the question makes a lot of sense, especially near midnight. Personally I came here looking for a way to "overload" the non-existing <- operator, thinking somebody must have overloaded both `__lt__` and `__neg__` to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 8):

Python doesn't have a `<-` operator.  Perhaps you have it backwards and meant `->`?

The only time you see that is in function annotations:

```
def func(a:int, b:str) -> str:
```

It lets the user know what the function *should* return.

Or, you could have seen something like this:

```
x<-1
```

which is basically testing if `x` is less than `-1`.

**Edit:**

Now that you have included the code, I can say for certain that it is the second answer.  This part:

```
if bullet[1]<-64
```

is basically testing if `bullet[1]` is less than `-64`.

Comment: This was a possible, albeit unlikely, answer to the OP's question at the time the answer was given, and was actually my first thought too.

Answer (score 5):

You are misreading the operator; it's `<` (lower than) `-64` (negative sixtyfour).

The line you show is a perfect example why the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) requires spaces around operators; the following is much clearer:

```
if bullet[1] < -64 or bullet[1] > 640 or bullet[2] < -64 or bullet[2] > 480:
```

Or, using chaining:

```
if not (-64 > bullet[1] > 640) or not (-64 > bullet[2] > 480):
```

Comment: okay thanks, but I dont see why so many thumbs down, been coding for more than 12 hours!

Comment: I think it was the lack of code in the first revision that did that.

Comment: so unfair, iCodez had -2 with his first answer, he edited and then got a thumbs up! :/

Comment: Och, it happens. People must've been surprised to learn about the annotation syntax. We'll see with time if the vote division remains this way. And no one can tell you what (if any) answer to mark as accepted either. :-)